# How would I make a java object smoothly & slowly follow the mouse cursor?

Tags: java, math, graphics, game-physics, trigonometry

I am making a little 2D game where the player can control a jet and this jet will follow their mouse cursor.

I got the math to function but when I decrease the acceleration speed, the plane starts to make more rigid, less smooth turns. Ex: (I added a trail so you can tell the angles it turns at)
jet trail with high accel speed:

[image: img1]

Notice the smoothness of that trail, but I want the plane to have that same smoothness even when i move it at a lower speed.

Currently, if I lowered the speed it looks more like this:
jet trail with low accel speed:

[image: img2]

Here is some code so you can see what equation I'm currently using to move the plane.
(here the speed is 10)

`int jet1DeltaX = (int) Math.round((Math.cos(theta)) * 10);`

`int jet1DeltaY = (int) Math.round((Math.sin(theta)) * 10);`

Note: theta is just the angle to look at the mouse using atan2.

.

Then I add the delta position to the original position.

`jet1.setPos(jet1.getX() + jet1DeltaX, jet1.getY() + jet1DeltaY);`

So my question is how would I slow down the jet's speed yet keep it moving in a smooth path?

Comment: Reduce the theta increment and do more calculations.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I'm currently doing this to calculate theta: theta = -Math.atan2(mouseX - jetX, mouseY - jetY);

What type of calculations should I do?

Comment: Chop your calculated theta into 20 pieces (divide by 20) and calculate the cartesian coordinates based on the smaller theta 20 times.  If 20 doesn't work, keep increasing the divisor until you get a smooth enough curve.